# why are spreading and destructing different even though they seem to do a similar job

Tags: javascript

Spreading and destructing work differently but they both seem to do a similar job. Why are they different, why not use just one?

```
let foo = [1,2,3];
let [o,t,th] = foo; //destructing works

let [o,t,th] = ...foo; // spreading doesn't work. will not compile

function test (a,b,c) {
 console.log(`${a}, ${b}, ${c}`)
}

test(...foo); //works but is sort of destructinng foo into a,b,c
test(foo) //assigns foo to a. b and c are undefined.
```

Comment: What is `foo` to begin with ?

Comment: oops `let foo = [1,2,3];`

Comment: `let [o,t,th] = ...foo;` should be `let [o,t,th] = [...foo];`

Comment: Cause they arent similar. Destructuring takes *certain* elements out of an array/object, spreading spreads *all the data* into a new array/object/arguments list

Comment: @talentedandrew didnt work `let [o,t,th] = [...foo];`

Comment: @ManuChadha whats the error in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Destructuring**

```
let [o,t,th] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Here you are declaring three variables and at the same time assigning them values *directly from array elements*.

> Therefore, destructuring is a way to directly access an object's(can
>   also be an array) properties without need to explicitly assign them to
>   variables.

It is equivalent to this:

```
let o = foo[0];
let t = foo[1];
let th = foo[2];
```

**Spread**

```
test(...foo);
```

Here you are spreading the array elements to *comma separated array elements*.

It is equivalent to this:

```
test(foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]);
```

Therefore these two are different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should beware that

```
[a, b, c]
```

and

```
func(a, b, c)
```

are two completely different things. Sure they both have commas and the same letters, but `a, b, c` in `func(a, b, c)` is not an array.

In `test(...foo)`, `...foo` spreads the content of the array as the comma separated arguments. It is not the same as passing an array into the function.

`let [o,t,th] = ...foo;` does not work because the specification does not allow such use. It doesn't make sense anyway. What are you trying to spread the content of `foo` into?

This, however, makes sense:

```
[...foo]  // spread the content into an array
```

Destructure only works when you are assigning one thing to a bunch of variables. Examples include:

```
let [a, b] = [1, 2];
let {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2};
function([a, b]){};
```